# Wiping my New MacBook Pro after Using Command Q to Stop Migration

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, disk-utility, migration

Got my new MB pro mid-2014 yesterday.  Began migrating over wi-fi only to learn that it will take 14 hours that I don't have.  After 45 minutes I halted on both computers using command Q.  My question, how do I safely wipe the new computer clean so that I can start again by transferring from time machine?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use Apple Mac's Disk Utility, select the disk or volume in the LH column that you wish to clear, specify a format and name and click on Erase. Also select Security Options if you wish to prevent any recovery of previously deleted files.

Comment: Actually OS X Utilities is a safer way to go. On reboot keep <CMD>-R held  down, then follow the instructions. This article explains: http://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/make-your-mac-feel-like-new-again-with-a-fresh-install-1697926482